# Parsing powershell output

Tags: powershell, parsing

I ran into such a problem, I don't know how best to solve it.
We have this script, determining the load on the CPU.

```
$pc = 'cmd'
 
try {$Connection = Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc -Count 2 -EA Stop}
catch {Write-Host "NO network connection to $PC" -fo Red; break}
 
try
{
    $option = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol Dcom
    $session = New-CimSession -ComputerName $pc -SessionOption $option -EA Stop
}
catch
{
    try
    {
        $option = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol Wsman
        $session = New-CimSession -ComputerName $pc -SessionOption $option -EA Stop
    }
    Catch {Write-Host "NOT connect to CimSession on $PC" -fo Red; break}
}
 
$ComputerSystem = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -CimSession $session
$CpuCores = $ComputerSystem.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
 
Write-Host 'Please wait for CPU Usage data to be collect...' -fo Yellow
 
if (Get-Counter -ListSet * -ComputerName $pc | ? Paths -Match "\\Процесс\(\*\)"){$CounterPath = "\Процесс(*)\% загруженности процессора"}
else {$CounterPath = "\Process(*)\% Processor Time"}
 
$CPU_Usage_Counter = (Get-Counter -Counter $CounterPath -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5 -ComputerName $pc -EA SilentlyContinue).CounterSamples | ? CookedValue -ne 0 | group InstanceName
 
$CPU_Usage_Data = $CPU_Usage_Counter | select Name,@{N='CPU_Usage_%';E={[math]::Round(($_.Group | %{$_.CookedValue} | measure -Average).Average/$CpuCores,2)}}
$CPU_Usage_Data | ? Name -ne '_total' | sort 'CPU_Usage_%' -Des | ft -a
 
Write-Host "NumberOfLogicalProcessors: $CpuCores"
$check = Write-Host "CpuUsageProcess" ( [math]::Round((100 - (($CPU_Usage_Data | ? Name -eq 'idle').'CPU_Usage_%')),2) ) -fo Yellow
#####---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$status = (($check).CpuUsageProcess -gt 5)
if($status)
{
    #Break
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'if!'
}
else
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'else!'
}
```

[image]

After execution, you need to extract the result of the "CpuUsageProcess" value and use it in the if / else condition

Comment: `Write-Host` does not emit anything for you to capture with `$check = Write-Host`. Its purpose is to output text to the display. Your variable `$check` will therefore be `$null` and thus you enter the `else {..}` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Theo points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68359945/parsing-powershell-output#comment120817329_68359945), `Write-Host` never emits any output - it simply causes PowerShell to write the input directly to the screen buffer.

Calculate the value(s) separately before calling `Write-Host`:

```
$check = [math]::Round((100 - (($CPU_Usage_Data | ? Name -eq 'idle').'CPU_Usage_%')),2)
Write-Host "CpuUsageProcess $check" -fo Yellow

if($check -gt 5){
    # ...
}
```